# Debugging Binary Search

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, binary-search

Below is an implementation of binary search, but something is wrong with it. Find it and fix it by modifying one line!

```
def binary_search(array, value, low, high):
    if high < low:
        return -1
    else:
        mid = (low + high)/2;
        if array[mid] > value:
            return binary_search(array, value, low, mid)
        elif array[mid] < value:
            return binary_search(array, value, mid+1, high)
        else:
            return mid
array = []
for i in xrange(10000):
    array.append(input())
for i in xrange(10000):
    value = input()
    answer = binary_search(array, value, 0, 9999)
    print("%d" % answer)
```

Input:

The input consists of the sorted array of length 10,000, followed by 10,000 queries. Each integer is given in its own line (there are 20,000 lines in total).

It is guaranteed that there are no duplicates in the array.

Output:

For every query value, output one line of output containing a single integer: the index that matches the query value, or -1 if the value is not in the array.

---

I've been trying to fix this code for days... I am quite sure that the parameters for the recursion inside if clause is wrong. Shouldn't it be:

```
if array[mid] > value:
            return binary_search(array, value, low, mid-1)
```

Because otherwise, if there is only one element in the array and the element > value then it will loop infinitely. But the resulting code still marked as wrong answer according to the evaluator!

Other suspects:

1. the ';' in `mid = (low + high)/2;`
   Though jarring, it still compiles just fine
2. `(low + high)/2`
   Because this is written in python 2.7, it's equivalent to `(low + high)//2` in python 3 right? So no problem here...

All kind of help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is a bit further up!

```
if high < low: #ERROR IS HERE
    return -1
```

This will lead to an infinite recursion if `value` is not in `array`.

**Reasoning:**

The value of `high` will **never** be lower than the value of `low`. This is because the only way these values are changed are by substituting them with `mid` in the recursive call. Since `mid=(high+low)//2`, eventually, they will end up being both `0` or `high`. And since `(0+0)//2 == 0` and `(high+high)//2 == high` you will end up doing infinite recursion until the stack blows. Thus, your fix seems like a simple `if high <= low:`.

*Now a new issue arises:*

What if we look for the value at `high` or `0`? Then we would get -1, because the values are both the same. The solution, make the `if` statement more precise:

`if high <= low and array[(low+high)//2] != value:`

This code makes sure that if the first condition holds, we also assure that the middle element in fact is not the value we are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for answering very thoroughly. However, this correction gave "Too much code was changed: only a single line should be changed, and not by too much (max distance = 30)". I'm starting to think there is something wrong with the evaluator!

Comment: @RawrDamn Mmmh I mean it is genuinely the only bug I could find. Without the additional statement the code still fails. Did you try the wrong solution I provided first, too? What evaluator is used? Does it check for functionality with a predefined example or does it do some other analysis like static reasoning on it?

Comment: Damn I feel so stupid. I modified the code to write the output into the file to make it easier for submitting. Figures that it leaves a newline at the last line, which makes it evaluate to wrong answer. Thank you!

The accepted correction was: return binary_search(array, value, low, mid-1)

Comment: @RawrDamn yeah I just realised that that works, too. Because then you actually make a change to the high and low variables by 1. It essentially is a different solution for the same problem. That the evaluator bugs out like that on new lines is concerning and definitely not your fault.